# Why aren't my TextViews getting centered?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to emulate a dock for a launcher with 3 text views evenly spaced out across said dock... For some reason I can't get my text views to center align with in there parent linear layouts, can someone please explain to me what is my issue here?

Here is my layout in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#99000000"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="100dp"
                 android:layout_height="100dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:background="@drawable/launcher_footer_icon"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="Internet Browser"
                 android:textColor="#000000"
                 android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/launcher_footer_icon"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Flight Tracker"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/launcher_footer_icon"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Airline Info"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As I've tested you layout there aren't any problems. Can you share an image what you have and what you want?

Comment: Why the separate `LinearLayouts`? Can't it work with all of them inside one?

Comment: @aegean I can tomorrow when I get back to work... The problem I'm having is that the 100dpx100dp TextViews are left aligned inside their parent LinearLayout when I'd like them centered... to be fair I've not tried running the activity that uses the layout and just used Eclipse's built in layout rendering to preview what the layout looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, I think you have too many inner layouts.. you can use layout_weight to achieve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:weightSum="15.0" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5.0" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Internet Browser"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5.0" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Flight Tracker"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5.0" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Airline Info"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The parent LinearLayout of each TextView I want to be 1/3 the width of the screen. i want the 100x100 TextView to be centered w/i the parent LinearLayout. I don't think your answer preserves the 100x100 TextView dimensions and will stretch them to be 1/3 the width of the screen.

Comment: Updated..the solution has too many nested layouts, but I think it gives what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out tomorrow once I get to work. I'm all ears to hear an alternate solution layout wise as to getting rid of so many nested layouts but maintaining the same appearance.